# How can I resolve Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk reference in dotnet test?

Tags: .net

I'm doing a dotnet test but I have this error:

> Make sure test project has a nuget reference of package
>   "Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" and framework version settings are
>   appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

Change your test project's target framework other than "net-standard",

"Microsoft decided that your tests should be compiled to target a platform so they know which platform to run your tests under and you get the behavior you expect for the platform you are targeting"

https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/.NET-Core-and-.NET-Standard#why-cant-my-tests-target-net-standard

https://github.com/nunit/dotnet-test-nunit/issues/122

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same error because I was trying to run `dotnet vstest` against `MyProject.Tests\bin\Debug\net5.0\ref\MyProject.Tests.dll` instead of `MyProject.Tests\bin\Debug\net5.0\MyProject.Tests.dll`.

Answer (score 0):

I tried many options but I managed to fix this issue by downgrading the version of Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk to 15.9.0